# RuntimeError: Exporting the operator cdist to ONNX opset version 9 is not supported

Tags: pytorch, onnx

I want to convert Prototypical Networks for Few-shot Learning to onnx.
Export `onnx`:

```
torch.onnx.export(model,(example_query_images, example_query_labels, x_pred), "super_resolution.onnx")
```

And it raise error `'RuntimeError: Exporting the operator cdist to ONNX opset version 9 is not supported. Please feel free to request support or submit a pull request on PyTorch GitHub.'`

Comment: I face the same problem. `cdist` in question is a `torch` operator that measures distance between each two pairs of vectors taken from a pair of sets; it is useful in knn-regression that is likely to be a part of yours (and mine) routine. It seems that the latest version of `torch` `onnx` converter still has no implementation for cdist. The 'solution' would be to either ask torch devs to implement it or volunteer to do it yourself.